# Relation between perceptron accuracy and epoch

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

Is it possible that the accuracy of perceptron decreases as I go through the training more times? In this case, I use the same training set several times.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the accuracy on training data set nor on test data set is stable as the epoch increases. Actually the [experimental data](http://www.amlbook.com/slides/iTunesU_Lecture03_April_10.pdf) indicated that the trend of either in-sample-error or out-sample-error is not even monotonic. And a "[pocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Variants)" strategy is often applied. Unlike early stop, the pocket algorithm keeps the best solution seen so far "in its pocket" instead of the last solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

This is a commonly studied phenomenon, the accuracy on never-before-seen data (testing data) start to decrease after certain point (after a certain number of passes through the training data-- what you call epochs). This phenomenon is called [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) and is well understood. You want to stop early, as early as possible or use regularization.